# Implement Watershed Segmentation in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, image-processing, image-segmentation, watershed

I am about to make an OS X App for image processing. I need to implement Watershed segmentation algorithm in Objective-c, I've found some opencv c++ code snippets but I am not familiar with c++ so it's hard to make it fully functional.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would probably be easier to learn Objective-C++ and make the few calls you need into OpenCV than reimplement it.

Here is a tutorial on using OpenCV from an iOS project using Objective-C++

https://www.objc.io/issues/21-camera-and-photos/face-recognition-with-opencv/

If you have specific questions about C++, it would be better to look them up in SO or create much more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks,this helps a lot. Have a nice day, sir. :)